# rsync --link-dest behaviour when run as sudo

Tags: linux, mac-osx, unix, rsync

In order to create regular backups, I'm using `rsync` together with `--link-dest` so as to create hard-links for unchanged files. For example:

```
rsync -ax \
      --partial --delete --delete-excluded --inplace \
      --exclude-from=/tmp/temp_excludes \
      --link-dest=/Volumes/Backup/current \
      /Users /Volumes/Backup/2012-06-25
```

**This works very well as long as I start the process from my normal user account.** Though as soon as I start the process using `sudo` it behaves erradically, meaning that `rsync` *copies* all the unchanged files instead of *hard-linking* them.

Since `sudo` modifies the environment, I've already also tried `sudo -E` in conjunction with making sure that my `sudoers` file has the corresponding option set. Well, that didn't work either.

**So, the question is, how can I run `rsync` using `sudo`?** Whereas the above example only shows a backup of the `Users` directory, I also need to backup some system files that I can only access as root.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you start `rsync` with `-i --dry-run` in order to find out why it wants to copy the unchanged files. The `-i` option will print out all updates along with a code that specifies why `rsync` considers that the files have changed (checksum, timestamp etc...). See the man page for a full explanation of the code.

You should probably also specify `--numeric-ids` in case the user ids are different on the source and the destination system.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try! My guts also tell me that it might have to do something with the "ignore ownership" flag of OS X that seems to be set as default for external devices (yak!).

Answer (score 1):

Although Oliver's suggestion is really appreciated, the solution to the problem is as follows:

When (external) devices are mounted on OS X, they have their corresponding **"ignore ownership" flag** set by default. OS X maintains a special database for that, accessible via `vsdbutil` (deprecated) and `diskutil`.

According to some googling, the reasoning behind this seems to be that the typical OS X user is a consumer product user who want to access their data that have been stored e.g. on an external USB disk from any other computer without going through the hassle of ownership, permissios, etc.

Hence, it is vital for the desired backup solution using `rsync` and `sudo` to **turn off this flag**:

```
# sudo diskutil enableOwnership <yourDeviceHere>
sudo diskutil enableOwnership /Volumes/Backup
```

Then, unmount and mount that device again to make sure that everything works fine. Finally, I have updated my `rsync` call to the following:

```
rsync -aNHAXx -i --fileflags --force-change \
      --partial --delete --delete-excluded --inplace \
      --exclude-from=/tmp/temp_excludes \
      --link-dest=/Volumes/Backup/current \
      /Users /Volumes/Backup/2012-06-25
```

The thing is stuffed into a (slightly modified) bash script now and allows for *incremental* daily backups onto an external USB disk under OS X.

Answer (score 1):

If you use [LBackup](http://www.lbackup.org) (an rsync wrapper) for your backup, one of the checks it performs when running on an OS X system is that the permissions for the destination disk image / drive are enabled.

If the permissions are not enabled, the backup will not proceed, a warning will be issued the command to enable permissions.

You may also find [this documentation page](http://www.lbackup.org/permissions) from the LBackup project to be of interest should you wish to continue using your own script.